# keep dropdown beside the text area is not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi guys i am trying to keep textarea and image upload button and select dropdown all in one line like below image.
[image]

And my code looks like this

```
<div class="col-md-10 div_qtype">
   <textarea name="question_text" class="question_text"></textarea>
   <input name="Select File" type="file" />
   <select id='question_options'>
     <option value="0">Multiple Choice</option>
     <option value="1">Check Box<option>
     <option value="2">Passing on to a client</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

And my design is looking like this

[image]

Can anyone help me how can i make my design like above one.Tia.

Comment: why you using two closing `</select>` tag and make different different column for all for that upload you need to make custom upload with css

Comment: by mistake i ahve make two select  tags.. as i am not that much familiar with css couldnt able to make.can you help me out.

Comment: ok give me some time will give you answer

Comment: okay sure  thank you so much.

Comment: please check i have created only for upload image with custom and icon [here you can check](https://jsfiddle.net/jwmbL7ce/1/)

Comment: okay what about the text area and dropdown one? is they looks fine?

Comment: depend upon you what you want because what ever you upload image above I think is google form and google have there own UI component so it's tough for you because you are new in UI right

Comment: yes its google form..i am new to UI thought..

Comment: so you have to learn more about UI eg: bootstrap and material design

Answer (score 0):

Seems it could be helpful to you. Button tag could be img too.

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

```js
const fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
  fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (fileElem) {
    fileElem.click();
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none">
<button id="fileSelect" >button or could be img</button>
```

Comment: this is not an actual answer